# How can I run my app without debugging?

Tags: android, android-emulator, eclipse-plugin

I'm running two Android apps in different emulators simultaneously. I want to simply "run" (run without debugging) the app and I want to debug the other. I would think that choosing "Run as Android app" as opposed to "Debug as Android app" would do this (in Eclipse), but the DDMS Perspective shows BOTH apps as being debugged (the green bug icon/glyph).

Comment: What's the problem? You can 'run' any code in debug mode and it is simply running. Unless you have breakpoints set or other things which might interfere with code execution, there shouldn't be a problem with it running in a debug session.

Comment: I guess it's not a big problem, but if one were not in debug mode, I wouldn't have to worry about it being the one that sends the mock location data via DDMS. As it is, I have to select the second app.